# Regarding Normal Map sculpting details

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, sculpting, normal-map

I have made a high poly hammer model, added sculpting details into it . created a normal map after baking, the sculpting details are missing in normal map of handle while the sculpting details are there in the hammer head normalmap. Have checked the normals of the entire hammer they are fine.

Have applied multires modifier into handle and head of hammer.

Can anyone help

Comment: hello, hard to tell, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: here is the file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=QPpB330Z" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/QPpB330Z/)

Comment: yes, if you duplicate the cylinder and bake from active it works, but it doesn't explain why it doesn't work currently, I hope someone will find out

Comment: can you please share the output as i am not able to bake it even after duplicating the cylinder. After duplicating do i need to deselect bake from mulitres and then activate Selected to active and then click on bake

Comment: yes, for your new cylinder, remove the multires and give it a subdivision surface modifier, set the bake as you say, give it a bit of ray distance